# Angular 2 v3 Routing - Can I share one path with multiple outlets

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, siblings

I am currently trying to create a dashboard that has several router-outlets. Is it possible to have each router-outlet to load a different component under the same path value.

I want to guarantee that the outlets load the right component and not have to rely on the path including the correct sibling segments.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve. Need to display multiple 'widgets' on the same page? Then you can just put multiple components on it. Each of these components can have its own router setup.

Comment: V3 only allows for one configuration for routing paths that is loaded during bootstrap. If this is the case the config takes only the first route path entry for each distinct path value in the config array. Component based route config is obsolete.